# MVC Copy input:file selected file to hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to copy selected file from `input:file` to `input:hidden` (placed inside another form

```
   $("#galleryInputFile").change(function () {
      $("#hiddenInput").val($(this).prop('files')[0]);
   });
```

that code works, but then the `hiddenInput` value is a string `[object File]`. On the server side, I need to read the content of that file, so how to replace from string `[object File]` to e.g `HttpPostedFileBase` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**

instead of using hidden field use another

```
 <input type='file' style='display:none;' >
```

and then copy